# $Y_n\xrightarrow{P}E(X_i)$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have this problem at hand

> $X_1,X_2,\cdots $ are iid random variables with finite second moments.Define$$Y_n={2\over n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i$$
>   Show that $Y_n\xrightarrow{P}E(X_1)$.

I know that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {(X_i-\mu)\over \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2}\xrightarrow{P}0$ as $n\to\infty$. And I can replace $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2$ with $n$ and things will still hold provided that ${\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2\over n^2} \to 0 $ as $n\to \infty$

I tried (since $\sigma_i$'s are finite) that say $\sigma_i
\lt k$    ($k$ finite). $${\sum\sigma_i^2\over n^2}\le {k^2\over n}\to 0 \text{  as  }n\to \infty$$ 
How ever I got stuck when I realised that Var$(X)=\sigma^2\implies $Var$(iX)=i^2\sigma^2$ implying$${\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni^2 \sigma_i^2\over n^2}\le k^2{n(n+1)(2n+1)\over 6n^2}\not\to 0 \text{ as }n\to \infty$$

So please help me proceed.

Comment: Starting from "I know that", what you are doing is a mystery. Why not simply compute/estimate $E(Y_n)$ and $\mathrm{var}(Y_n)$? Note that $$\left(\frac2{n(n+1)}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\Theta\left(\frac1n\right).$$

Comment: I got the point. Thanks.. Actually I am new to convergence, so I tend to mess things up...